# Installing Gunicorn using Cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, gunicorn

How can I install [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)?

I cant seem to find the Gunicorn Package on Cygwin...Unless I'm understanding the [issue](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/407) on github wrong, I think it does support Gunicorn.

Also I found this in the [changelog](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/news.html#id5):

> ## 0.17.2 / 2013-01-07
>
> - optimize readline
> - make imports errors more visiblle when loading an app or a logging class
> - fix tornado worker: don’t pass ssl options if there are none
> - fix PEP3333: accept only bytetrings in the response body
> - fix support on CYGWIN platforms

Comment: That means you can install it from sources on Cygwin like you would do on Linux

Comment: Thanks for your response... I will install ubuntu to use Gunicorn `:)`